# Blazor webassembly on IIS 10 - 404 for some dlls

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, blazor-webassembly

My Blazor webassembly app runs fine localy. When I deploy it to IIS 10 on a Windows Server 2016, the app fails to load some of dlls. This is a screenshot from Fiddler:
[image]

Two of the red dlls are system and anoher one is the application dll. All the dlls are present in the wwwroot_framework_bin folder.

And this is what I see in the Chrome's Developer Console tab:
[image]

Comment: Please try the following operation.1, change other browser IE or edge to check whether it reports same error. 2,Create a new empty blazor web assembly application and deploy to IIS. I create an empty one, system dll and mscorlib dll load successfully. 3, What's your version of asp.net core? I found that 3.2 may have this issue but 5.0 won't. You'd better update it to 5.0. 4, Add <BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources> in web.config and run it again. 5, Clean the solution rebuild and republish.

Comment: Thanks, Bruce. I tried Edge. I created an empty Blazor app and deployed it to the same server as the first one. The same error!

Comment: Are you able to request the DLLs are returning 404s manually using a browser? Maybe something else is getting in the way to downloading those files?

Comment: What's the version of you blazor application? Please tell me the detail information about version.

Comment: Upgraded to 5.0, all the same.
In IIS log, the error is 404 2 1260, which is Windows error ERROR_ACCESS_DISABLED_BY_POLICY. I must've missed something in the server setup, can'\t figure out what.

Comment: @Eliyahu Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Nope. I've given up on that server and deployed to another server with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

DLLs (and other filetypes that Blazor will request on your server) are filtered and not served by default.

Go inside the request filtering in IIS Manager and explicitly allow ".dll" file extensions.

You can also do this in the `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
        ...
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    ....
                    <add fileExtension=".dll" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        ...
</system.webServer>
```

Some others you will surely need to allow: **.js**, **.wasm** and **.json**